# Why do I get different R2 when comparing SEM and LM?

Tags: r, regression

I traditionally use linear regression models, but wanted to learn how to use SEM as I sometimes have predictor variables that are predicted be other predictors, and so I tried to compare the output of the `lm()` function and the `sem()` function in the Lavaan package.

As an example: The main variable I want to predict is `Y`, using variables `X1` and `X2`, but `X2` is predicted by `X3` and `X4`.

When using the `lm()` function for `Y ~ X1 + X2` I get an R^2 of 0.38, and for `X2 ~ X3 + X4` I get 0.2.
When entering both those equations into a model variable simultaneously which I input into the `sem()` function, I get R^2 of 0.16 and 0.06 respectively. When I remove the `X2 ~ X3 + X4` from the SEM model, I get 0.38, which I do not understand

I am not interested in the code, but I wonder why the R^2 is lower for the same two models? I tried looking at the Lavaan help vignette, but still don't get why.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting different valeus of R-squared across your two models is because you are using different methods to fit them. There are different assumptions for linear regression than there are for structural equation models (SEMs).

In general you should not use R-squared to assess the predictive performance of a model. Rather, look at the predictive error, root-mean-square-error, and where appropriate AIC and BIC.